# Open plots in a null device

Tags: r, plot, suppress, r-grid

I'm using the `treemap` package and I'm happy with how `tmPlot` arranges plot rectangles, I want to extract the grid for my own different plots. An example is as follows:

```
library(treemap)
data(GNI2010)
dat <- tmPlot(GNI2010,
          index=c("continent", "iso3"),
          vSize="population",
          vColor="GNI",
          type="value")[[1]][[1]]
```

This way I can store the coordinates of the rectangles I want. The catch is that it produces a plot as well. I can see a couple of ways to prevent the plot from being produced:

```
.Call("R_GD_nullDevice", PACKAGE = "grDevices")
#tmPlot here
dev.off()
```

This would essentially send the plot to a NULL device, but it gives a warning:

```
R_GD_nullDevice is deprecated and will be removed shortly
```

I'd rather my code didn't break this way. I could also strip out the relevant parts of `tmPlot` so that only the parts I wanted. This is possible, but would be a bit of a nuisance. I intend that a function containing this goes inside a package.

In short, is it possible to suppress graphics?

Comment: maybe with `grid.grabExpr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way that seems to work is to open a NULL `pdf` device. I originally tried this with the `png` device, which doesn't work.

```
pdf(NULL)
dat <- tmPlot(GNI2010,
          index=c("continent", "iso3"),
          vSize="population",
          vColor="GNI",
          type="value")[[1]][[1]]
dev.off()
```

Comment: This is the suggested workaround the [development version of R] (http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html) `The ‘internal’ graphics device invoked by .Call("R_GD_nullDevice", package = "grDevices") has been removed: use pdf(file = NULL) instead.` (under Deprecated and Defunct).

Comment: Thanks @mnel. I actually found the answer through some of the `knitr` issue reports. There was an issue with `pdf(file=NULL)` producing a file called NA which has since been fixed.