# Suppress plots in R (mac)

Tags: r

I am currently using R to generate some statistics for a couple hundred time-series from a simulation. I am employing something called the 'earlywarnings' package. The particular function I am using returns various statistics along with their respective plots. However, since I need to check hundreds of these things (in a loop), I'd like to know if there is a way to suppress this function from plotting every time.

I am new to R and I don't know how to see the contents of the package in order to change the code to achieve my goals.

Thank you for your help.

**** Edit *****

I have checked the package's documentation and there's is not mention of an option to stop the function from plotting.

Below is the code needed to run an example. Use any time-series:

```
generic_ews(mytimeseries, winsize = 25, detrending = c("no", "gaussian",
                                            "loess", "linear", "first-diff"), bandwidth = NULL, span = NULL,
        degree = NULL, logtransform = FALSE, interpolate = FALSE,
        AR_n = FALSE, powerspectrum = FALSE)
```

Comment: [Please post an MCVE.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: does this work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725620/open-plots-in-a-null-device

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation of the [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/earlywarnings/earlywarnings.pdf). Search your function and look if there is an option to suppress plots.

Another possibility is to load the [*tar.gz](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/earlywarnings_1.0.59.tar.gz) file from the CRAN server and open the file/function you use.